# Windows NodeJS: always get either "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open" or "Error: EACCES: permission denied, open"

Tags: node.js, windows

Here is my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');
var logFile = fs.createWriteStream('C:/text.txt', { flags: 'a' });
// Or 'w' to truncate the file every time the process starts.
var logStdout = process.stdout;

console.log = function () {
logFile.write(util.format.apply(null, arguments) + '\n');
logStdout.write(util.format.apply(null, arguments) + '\n'); 
}
console.error = console.log;
```

No matter what I type instead of "C:/text.txt" I either get

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

or

> Error: EACCES: permission denied, open

I tried everything such as "run as administrator" and "elevate", but when it's not the second error message, it's the first one; and when it's not the first one, it's the second one.

I'm soooo confused

Comment: On windows I think you might want to use 'C:\text.txt'

Comment: this way I get "Error: EACCES: permission denied, open",  and I gave full permissions to "everyone"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For windows it's better to use `\\` in the path to avoid some problems.

```
C:\\text.txt
```

This path I use to include pdftk.exe:

```
C:\\PDFtk\\bin\\pdftk.exe
```

Comment: this way I get "Error: EACCES: permission denied, open",  and I gave full permissions to "everyone"

Comment: So you need to change disk `C` permissions `https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754344(v=ws.11).aspx`

Or you can use another disk, like `D` if you don't want to change permissions or run command line as administrator and start node

Comment: "using another disk" was the answer I was looking for, thanks!